# how to make a converter with spinner and listview

Tags: android

I made this xml for a converter and I need it to convert from the values in the spinner like Acre, hectare and ... and give me the result in the list view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I made this code in java:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.area);

    Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.Area, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

What I need is to get the value from the spinner (like acre value) and insert the result to the list view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick selected value from spinner and then add to listview.